# How do I find a record in Ember with association promises?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

So I have a model

```
App.CourseBook = DS.Model.extend({
  // Associations
  course: DS.belongsTo('course', { async: true }),
  book: DS.belongsTo('book', { async: true })
});
```

And in my serializer I only embed the course and book ids. I don't include the course and book data.

At one point I need to go get that data inside a find function

```
course.get('courseBooks').then(function(course_books){
  var course_book = course_books.find(function(cb){
    return cb.get('book').then(function(cb_book){
      return cb_book === book;
    });
  });
  // Do something with course_book...
});
```

This doesn't work because `cb.get('book')` returns a promise as expected.

So, short of including the books in the courseBook serializer, how do I search the association of a model when a promise is involved?

If I include the data it is as simple as

```
var course_book = course_books.find(function(cb){
  return cb.get('book') === book;
});
```

But I don't want to include it if at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve the promise first.

```
var all =course_books.getEach('book');
return Ember.RSVP.all(all).then(function(records){
  return records.filter...
});
```

Sorry, phone programming is a little rough

Comment: Beauty, that is exactly the clean solution I was hoping for! I had to `return cb.get('book.content') === book` but I can live with that. Thanks man!